# How to fetch data ( without duplicates records ) from two different tables ? where both tables have common value

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1

```
newpancard

id | name | cardno | status |
-----------------------------
1  | name1| 909099 | done   |
2  | name2| 800099 | done   |
3  | name3| 965099 | pending|
```

Table 2

```
oldpancard

id | name | cardno | status |
-----------------------------
1  | name4| 111119 | done   |
2  | name5| 323239 | done   |
3  | name6| 734349 | pending|
4  | name7| 609099 | done   |
```

can we get fetch data from both tables where `status = done` in both tables?

I am trying the following query but getting duplicates data in bulk.

```
SELECT tb1.*, tb2.* 
FROM `newpancard` tb1 
JOIN `oldpancard` tb2 
  ON tb1.status = tb2.status
```

please correct me. Thanks

Comment: You just need a condition saying `status='done'`

Comment: @Qirel yes we have only condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you actually want a `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM newpancard WHERE status='done'
UNION
SELECT * FROM oldpancard WHERE status='done'
```

We use a `UNION` (rather than `UNION ALL`) so we don't get duplicate records from `newpancard` and `oldpancard`

Output (from your sample data):

```
id  name    cardno  status
1   name1   909099  done
2   name2   800099  done
1   name4   111119  done
2   name5   323239  done
4   name7   609099  done
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e481e0/1)

Comment: Great. Glad to be of help.